# Which is the best php extension for reading xml file?

Tags: php, xml

Which is the best php [extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php) for reading xml file from absolute path?
The xml file is simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<online>
    <coountry value='us'>
        <user hours='10' name='user1' id='1' />
        <user hours='9' name='user2' id='2' />
        <user hours='8' name='user3' id='3' />
    </country>
</online>
```

From the xml I will need to loop through the country tag and use each user tag attributes.

Comment: You mean a file path? Using what tool / library? Can you show some code?

Comment: I mean like reading file from absolute path /home/user/www/system/online.xml. I don't have any cause I can't figure out how to properly read the xml.

Comment: all PHP's XML extensions by default support reading a file from a *file* path (that is what you mean, "absolute path" means something different). You can use whichever XML library you like.

Comment: What do you want to do with the XML file?

Comment: @Pekka, thank you for clearing it out! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on how complex or large the XML file is. If it's a simple file or is relatively short I'd go for SimpleXML. Can you post a sample of the XML? You might get a better answer then.

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to do with the xml?
The way to handle complex XML documents is:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('/home/user/www/system/online.xml');
```

However, without knowing what you intend to get from the XML, it is hard to suggest the right parser.

Comment: Edited the main post adding the xml and what i'll do with it.